# Favorite Economics Podcast?

Tags: soft-question

What is your favorite Economics podcasts? More on the research side please.

Since I have too few words, here are mine:

- https://www.aeaweb.org/research/podcasts
- I used to like [EconTalk](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/econtalk/id135066958?mt=2&app=podcast), but it's not really about Econ anymore.

Comment: One podcast per answer, please. Then it is clear which podcast people are voting for.

Comment: Okay, I'll add mine as answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

[AEA Research Highlights](https://www.aeaweb.org/research/podcasts): discusses a recent publication in AEA journals with the authors of the article. Covers all areas in econ but applied micro is definitely overrepresented.

Answer (score 1):

[IMF Podcasts](https://www.imf.org/en/News/Podcasts): Listen to the brightest minds in the field of economics and development discuss their latest research and deconstruct global economic trends.

Compared to 'The Uncertain Hour' podcast, you'll find a much more diverse variety of topics with guests from all across the globe discussing regional, national and global issues here.

Answer (score 1):

[EconTalk](https://www.econtalk.org/): The grandfather of Econ podcasts. Russ Roberts invites guests to discuss a variety of topics. Lately, not really about Economics anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[The Uncertain Hour](https://www.marketplace.org/shows/the-uncertain-hour/): Each season, we explain the weird, complicated and often unequal American economy — and why some people get ahead and some get left behind.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't listened to it for a while, but I liked the Freakonomics podcast.
https://freakonomics.com/series/freakonomics-radio/